# Proving that $R^2$ is $r^2$

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression

$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\varepsilon $ is a simple linear model.

We know $R^2=1-\frac{SSE/(n-k-1)}{SST/(n-1)} $ where

$SSE=Y'(I-H)Y=\sum(y_i-\hat{y})^2$

and $SST=Y'(I-P_1)Y=\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2$

(for $H=X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ and $P_1=\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{11'}$ and $\mathbf{1}=(1,\cdots,1)_{1\times n}'$, $Y=(y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n)'$,$X=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{11}\\ 
 1& x_{21}\\ 
 \vdots&\vdots \\ 
 1&x_{n1 } 
\end{bmatrix}$)

Define $r=\frac{\sum (y_i-\bar{y})(x_i-\bar{x})}{\sqrt{\sum (y_i-\bar{y})^2\sum (x_i-\bar{x} )^2}}$.

**Show $R^2=r^2$**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your thoughts about tackling this problem and share with us the progress we have made, so we can focus on what will help you understand this material.

Comment: This does not answer your question 100%, but it should give you enough hints to get started on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Pearson.27s_correlation_and_least_squares_regression_analysis

Comment: So your formula for $r$ is the general formula for a correlation, but are you sure that what you want is $\bar x$ in there (this is probably where you trouble lies)?

Comment: The question seems to be using the *adjusted* $R^2$, which won't equal the square of $r$.

Comment: [This question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99669/the-equivalence-of-sample-correlation-and-r-statistic-for-simple-linear-regressi) also asks why $R^2=r^2$.

Answer (score 2):

This answer will be written in a several regressors setting. You can directly apply it to the your simple case of only one regressor.

Let $N=I_n-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}'$

$R^2=\frac{SSE}{SST}=\frac{(Xb)'NXb}{Y'NY}$

The square of the sample correlation is $\displaystyle r^2(\hat{Y},Y)=\frac{\left(\sum(\hat{y_i}-\bar{\hat{y}})(y_i-\bar{y})\right)^2}{ SST\cdot SSE}=\frac{(b'X'NY)'b'X'NY}{(Xb)'NXb \cdot Y'NY}$

Note: $N$ is symmetric and idempotent and $Ne=e$, and $X'e=0$.

$b'X'NY=b'X'NXb+b'X'Ne=b'X'NXb$.

So $r^2(\hat{Y},Y)=\frac{(b'X'NXb)'b'X'NXb}{(Xb)'NXb \cdot Y'NY}=\frac{(Xb)'NXb}{Y'NY}=R^2$

Comment: This is not the formula for $r$ invoked in the question: how exactly are your formula and the OP's formula related?

Comment: @whuber As soon as I get some free time, I'll answer your question.

Comment: @whuber is it clearer now? And by the way, why is this being marked as a duplicate when the mod's don't provide a link of the question from which this one would be considered a duplicate of?

Comment: (1) I think there's still a gap: your formula for $r^2$ still differs from that used in the question. (2) The link to the duplicate is given at the top in a highlighted box beginning "This question already has an answer here:". (3) No moderators were involved in closing this thread: five high-reputation community members closed it.