# Showing Proof for $r^2 = R^2$

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation, mathematical-statistics

[image]

I need to show proof that r^2 is equal to R^2 given the defined r is the sample correlation between two vectors x and y.

Comment: I'm sure this is an answer in this site or math.stackexchange... This is a homework problem, maybe give your attempt?

Comment: It has been answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99669/the-equivalence-of-sample-correlation-and-r-statistic-for-simple-linear-regressi)