# Proove that conditional expectation of residual is 0

Tags: least-squares, residuals

Is there a mathematical proove that conditional expection of residual is 0?

i.e. E(Residual | X) = 0

Comment: Other related questions https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369658/expected-value-of-the-residuals https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/469212/proof-that-the-mean-of-predicted-values-in-ols-regression-is-equal-to-the-mean-o

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I think since these questions come frequently, we need to take one a canonical and mark the others duplicate.

Comment: @User1865345 the first link that I gave is the one that many others link to. I mentioned some others because they are not easily found and may give the OP some more insight. The duplicate answers do not show up directly in the canonical question and only via the 'linked questions'.

Comment: Whether this is true depends on what the model is.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Hi Wuber, We are using OLS model. I was confused - Does the OLS always ensures, that `E(Residual | X) = 0` ?

Comment: even in case of data contains endogeneity ... and we run OLS on it ... the OLS still ensures it, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

What is residual $\mathbf e? $

Specifically $$\mathbf e = \mathbf y -\mathbf P\mathbf y, \tag 1$$

where $\mathbf P:= \mathbf X\left(\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf X\right) ^{-1}\mathbf X^\mathsf T. $

For fixed $\mathbf X, $

\begin{align}\mathbb E[\mathbf e|\mathbf X] &= (\mathbf I-\mathbf P) \mathbb E[\mathbf y|\mathbf X]\\&= (\mathbf I-\mathbf P)\mathbf X\boldsymbol \beta\\ &= \left[\mathbf X-\mathbf X\left(\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf X\right) ^{-1}\mathbf X^\mathsf T\mathbf X\right]\boldsymbol\beta\\ &=\mathbf 0.\tag 2\end{align}

What happens when $\bf X$ is random? Can the result be valid? Does it make any difference in the treatment above? Can any comment be made on unconditional expectation $\mathbb E[\mathbf e]? $

Comment: But will it still be true ....if model contains endogenity?

Comment: I.e.  `E(Residual | X) = 0` will still hold true?

Comment: The classical LRM assumes exogeneity of independent variables: that means $\varepsilon$ is uncorrelated with information based on $\mathbf x$ i.e. $\mathbb E[\boldsymbol\varepsilon |\mathbf X]= \mathbf 0.$ That is the basis. Without exogeneity, then, can you infer such result? Think.

Comment: What if the model contains endogenity and we still fit OLS on it .... will this result still hold?

Comment: That would be a separate question that you can ask in a different post.